# How to apply data prediction algorithms on networking data?

Tags: algorithm, linear-regression, prediction

I want to use data prediction algorithms on Network data.so can anyone point me on the right direction please.
which algorithm is most effective and how to apply data on those formula's.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please read [ask], that will come in handy. Your question as it is now is regarded as offtopic on [so]. Try editing it, with some code you have tried perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to be more specific if you want a more detailed answer. Until then, here's something to help you get started.

When you say network data, the first thing I think about is streams of data packets, streams of transactions, and such. These usually arrive at great speed (e.g. it could be more than thousands per minute), are potentially infinite (all the elements won't fit into into a working memory; the best you can hope for is to store a very small fraction of elements), and usually you want your prediction model to adapt to recent examples while using "small" amount of memory.

It is tempting to say that we could learn a model on a sample of data. However, the model you learn today could no longer be valid the next week---you want to be able to detect these changes and adapt your model continuously.

There is a whole branch of data mining dedicated to scenarios of this type; it is called *data stream mining*.

Depending on what you want to predict, I suggest that you consult [Data Stream Mining: A Practical Approach](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~abifet/MOA/StreamMining.pdf) by the team that develops [MOA](http://moa.cms.waikato.ac.nz/) (which stands for Massive Online Analysis and is, as far as I know, the leading data stream mining toolbox); I also recommend the [chapter on data stream mining](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch4.pdf) from the [Mining of Massive Data Sets](http://www.mmds.org/) book by Leskovec et al. The [Wiki article on data stream mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_stream_mining) is a good palce to look for further references.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response:).yes its more related to interface Bandwidth data.am choosing linear regression or gradient boost algorithms to analyse and predict those data.but i dont know how to apply interface history records to those formula's.can you pls help on this.

Comment: Why don't you first try simple methods, such as "damping" average? You give higher weights to recent values, and basically ignore old values.

Comment: Search for "incremental regression," there are extensive explanations available. For example: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23481/are-there-algorithms-for-computing-running-linear-or-logistic-regression-param